# Lubuntu sound icon not reopening

Tags: lubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 with Lubuntu and I am having an issue with the sound icon. When I open it and close it it will not open anymore. Only when I restart my computer will it open again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling indicator-sound

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

Comment: this worked but now I am having other issues!